# Is there a way to only re-render objects that have changed values in java AWT Canvas?

Tags: java, graphics, awt

As a typical example, say you want to render the background image only once at the start, is there any way to do some kind of layer separation or anything that would save having to re-render everything on screen every single time even when nothing is changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways:

1. Use a double buffered image.
2. Override paint(...) method.
3. Override update(...) method.

Use the 1. way if you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: Excellent! I'll try doing the first for now and perhaps in the future once I'm more experienced. Thank you so much